# Tool to convert stored procedures from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am already tried like a below tools for conversion

1. Mysql workbench
2. Dataloader (trial version)
3. DRPU database converter (trial version)

But, still i can't able to convert Stored procedures from sql server to mysql.

if anybody have an idea about that, give a suggestion to me

Thank you.